# numpy method to do ndarray to vector mapping as in Matlab's delsq demo?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

It Matlab you can easily set up a numbered grid and map operators to 'vectorized' form and back via various indexing tricks. It is not too hard to write this more explicitly but I am wondering if there is a numpy method for doing this? Perhaps via numpy.nditer?

This bit of code (see the mathworks example) gets you from vector u to Matrix U using the ordering stored in the matrix grid G:

```
U = G;
U(G>0) = full(u(G(G>0)));
```

Reference:

http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/delsqdemo.html

Comment: Can you add another example of what do you want?

Comment: The link has the mathworks example. Using a labeled grid is standard in matlab for simple finite difference schemes. My question is: "is there a "built in" way to do that in numpy/scipy?".

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, the equivalent is just `U = G.copy(); U[G > 0] = u` (Noting the difference between `U` and `u` and assuming `u` is a sequence of the right length.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following reproduces the Demo.  The numbering in `G` is different, but the numbers are just labels (the labeled grid that puzzled me).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def numgrid(n):
    """
    NUMGRID Number the grid points in a two dimensional region.
    G = NUMGRID('R',n) numbers the points on an n-by-n grid in
    an L-shaped domain made from 3/4 of the entire square.
    adapted from C. Moler, 7-16-91, 12-22-93.
    Copyright (c) 1984-94 by The MathWorks, Inc.
    """
    x = np.ones((n,1))*np.linspace(-1,1,n)
    y = np.flipud(x.T)
    G = (x > -1) & (x < 1) & (y > -1) & (y < 1) & ( (x > 0) | (y > 0))
    G = np.where(G,1,0) # boolean to integer
    k = np.where(G)
    G[k] = 1+np.arange(len(k[0]))
    return G

def delsq(G):
    """
    DELSQ  Construct five-point finite difference Laplacian.
    delsq(G) is the sparse form of the two-dimensional,
    5-point discrete negative Laplacian on the grid G.
    adapted from  C. Moler, 7-16-91.
    Copyright (c) 1984-94 by The MathWorks, Inc.
    """
    [m,n] = G.shape
    # Indices of interior points
    G1 = G.flatten()
    p = np.where(G1)[0]
    N = len(p)
    # Connect interior points to themselves with 4's.
    i = G1[p]-1
    j = G1[p]-1
    s = 4*np.ones(p.shape)

    # for k = north, east, south, west
    for k in [-1, m, 1, -m]:
       # Possible neighbors in k-th direction
       Q = G1[p+k]
       # Index of points with interior neighbors
       q = np.where(Q)[0]
       # Connect interior points to neighbors with -1's.
       i = np.concatenate([i, G1[p[q]]-1])
       j = np.concatenate([j,Q[q]-1])
       s = np.concatenate([s,-np.ones(q.shape)])
    # sparse matrix with 5 diagonals
    return sparse.csr_matrix((s, (i,j)),(N,N))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print numgrid(6)
    print delsq(numgrid(6)).todense()
    G = numgrid(32)
    D = delsq(G)
    N = D.shape[0]
    rhs = np.ones((N,1))
    u = linalg.spsolve(D, rhs) # vector solution
    U = np.zeros(G.shape) # map u back onto G space
    U[G>0] = u[G[G>0]-1]
    plt.contour(U)
    plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The MATLAB demo uses `axis square ij`, hence the difference in orientation of the attached contour plot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by a 'labeled grid' or 'numbered grid'.

It looks like the Demo depends on two functions, `numgrid` and `delsqr`.  You can probably look at the code from within MATLAB.  But online I found

http://chmielowski.eu/POLITECHNIKA/Dydaktyka/AUTOMATYKA/AutoLab/Matlab/TOOLBOX/MATLAB/DEMOS/NUMGRID.M

http://chmielowski.eu/POLITECHNIKA/Dydaktyka/AUTOMATYKA/AutoLab/Matlab/TOOLBOX/MATLAB/DEMOS/DELSQ.M

The date is 1991, so they are written in old fashioned MATLAB, with none on the newer 'vectorization' or any fancy mapping tricks (that I can see).  The only special thing is the use of sparse matricies (`delsq` returns a sparse matrix).  It generates the surface that has been the Mathworks logo for a long time.

So translating these to `numpy` should be straight forward.  To generate the sparse matrix you need `scipy.sparse`.  `MATLAB` `sparse(i,j,s)` => `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(s, (i,j))`.

But if your concern is more with the indexing step:

```
U = G;
U(G>0) = full(u(G(G>0)));
```

With matching `data` arrays, the following are equivalent

Octave (MATLAB):

```
U = data;
u=(0:75)*0.1+10;
U(data>0)=u(data(data>0));
contour(U)
```

`numpy`

```
U=np.zeros(data.shape)
u = np.arange(0,76)*.1+10
U[data>0]=u[data[data>0]]
contour(U)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that code. It might still be worth putting a link to a numpy version of numgrid or delsq if anyone finds any. It is not tricky stuff to write but it is easy to get little things wrong and waste a few minutes thinking numpy indexing works differently somehow.

Comment: This is MATLAB demo code, written by C Moler years ago to highlight the new sparse matrix.  The labeled matrix is part of one way of handling the boundary conditions for finite difference (and finite element) problems.  Someone else may have translated these functions, but I don't expect them to be a basic part of the `numpy` toolbox.  I have added my own translation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but your question seems to be about [boolean indexing and assignment](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) rather than having anything to do with the specific example using `delsq`, etc.

To expand on my comment, it sounds like you just want: (using `x` instead of `u` to avoid confusion over capitalization)

```
U = G.copy()
U[G > 0] = x
```

As a more concrete example, let's say you have an array (let's use the one in the example, ipython's `%paste x` command makes this easier):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                 [ 0,  1,  6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66,  0],
                 [ 0,  2,  7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 37, 47, 57, 67,  0],
                 [ 0,  3,  8, 13, 18, 23, 28, 38, 48, 58, 68,  0],
                 [ 0,  4,  9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69,  0],
                 [ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70,  0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71,  0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72,  0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 33, 43, 53, 63, 73,  0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 34, 44, 54, 64, 74,  0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75,  0],
                 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])

# Generate some random data to put in place of the 1..75 in the original
newvals = np.random.randint(100, 500, len(data[data > 0]))

# If we wanted to modify data in-place, we'd skip the copy
new = data.copy()
new[data > 0] = newvals
print new
```

This yields:

```
[[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 385 417 399 394 104 474 328 396 129 230   0]
 [  0 189 440 298 120 278 115 148 142 454 405   0]
 [  0 490 484 240 312 339 192 212 287 468 225   0]
 [  0 348 300 486 485 162 159 258 418 335 110   0]
 [  0 495 496 392 364 215 122 213 222 412 122   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0 442 188 325 248 225   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0 431 233 141 307 339   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0 259 325 102 131 333   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0 458 381 127 333 170   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0 454 229 162 216 192   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

On a side note, the matlab example is dealing with sparse arrays. `scipy.sparse` offers multiple sparse array types, and not all of them support this type of indexing.  However, if you were dealing with sparse arrays, you'd just do `sparse_array.data[:] = newvals` to change the values while keeping the sparsity structure.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some edits (the newvals[data[data > -1]] is the only important bit). After the edits it seems to work on my home dev version of numpy. I was probably just doing something dumb on my work setup but I will check tomorrow and confirm.

Comment: @mathtick - Glad to help. However, your edits would have resulted in incorrect code. Changing the `0`'s to `-1`'s doesn't change anything, but `new[data > -1] = newvals[data[data > -1]]` is entirely incorrect (and will result in an error, depending on the exact values and data types).  Maybe I'm still misunderstanding what you want to do?

Comment: I think you are using this differently that what is done in the matlab example. When I run your code, the second entry of newvals is not being put in the data==2 spot. The numbers in data can be in any order if that helps clarify the full usage.